# Format the double quoted json escape string in ARM template

Tags: azure-rm-template

I have to bind the service url dynamically for the swagger import via ARM deployments.

I was trying to format the escaped json string in the ARM templates as below

```
"value": "[format('\"{\"swagger\":\"2.0\",\"host\":\"{0}\"}\"', parameters('ApimServiceUrl'))]",
```

But i am getting as 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
How to bind the ARM parameter value in escaped string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
"[concat('\"{\"swagger\":\"2.0\",\"host\":\"', parameters('ApimServiceUrl'), '\"}\"')]"
```

Also, i think everything inside json should be escaped with `\\\`:

```
"[concat('\"{\\\"swagger\\\":\\\"2.0\\\",\\\"host\\\":\\\"', parameters('ApimServiceUrl'), '\\\"}\"')]"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Above script is works fine. I could see the format function in the below link.                                                                                     
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#format. Will it possible to use the format function for the above case?

Comment: lol, i literally just checked the same page and missed it. sigh. usually format function is a little funky when you have `{}` inside the actual string. concat would be simplier to get working properly. also, if this helped you - consider accepting this answer ;)